# Large minimal degree of a graph implies that it is connected

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a graph of order n.
>   (a) If $δ(G) ≥ (n−1)/2$, then prove that $G$ is connected.
>   (b) If $δ(G) ≥ (n−2)/2$, then show that $G$ need not be connected.

Here $δ(G)$ is the minimal degree of $G$. $G$ is connected if every two vertices in $G$ are connected, meaning vertices $v,u$ are connected if there is a $vu$ walk in $G$.

This is what I know, just need help connecting the dots!

Comment: Does $G$ need to be a simple graph?

Comment: Yes it does need to be simple.

Answer (score 1):

For part A), grab two vertices $u,v$ from $V(G)$ and suppose they not are adjacent. By simplicity, we have $|N(u)| \ge \delta(G) \ge \dfrac{n-1}{2}$, and similarly for $v$. Since $u$ and $v$ are not adjacent, $|N(u) \cup N(v)| \le n-2$ since $u$ and $v$ are not in the union (as if so, they would be adjacent). Then $|N(u) \cap N(v)| = |N(u)| + |N(v)| - |N(u) \cup N(v)| \ge \dfrac{n-1}{2} + \dfrac{n-1}{2} - (n-2)  = 1$, so they have at least one common neighbor, and thus since every two nonadjacent vertices have a common neighbor, the graph is connected.

This is from West's *Introduction to Graph Theory*, proposition 1.3.15.

Answer (score 0):

For (a), an alternative characterization of connectivity is that $G$ is connected if and only if for each partition of $V$ into $(V_1, V_2)$ (i.e. $V=V_1\cup V_2$, $V_1$ and $V_2$ are disjoint, and $V_1,V_2$ are nonempty), there exists $u\in V_1, v\in V_2$ such that $uv\in E$. Let $(V_1, V_2)$ be a partition of $V$. Then either $V_1$ or $V_2$ has at most $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ vertices. What does this tell us about $\delta(G)$?

For (b), you just need to find a counterexample.